# How to use OpenFileDialog in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dll

I want to do a music player based on the Unity3D engine.

Apparently, `System.Windows.Forms.dll` is not referenced in the default project, so I found the file in `System.dll` from the reference of the project.

I am using the `OpenFileDialog` class to read the folder selected by the user, but the Unity3D engine has is giving me the following error:

[image: Error 01]

According to my search for information and problems on the Internet, the .NET Framework version of the DLL file is too high to make it incompatible.

So, I created a `WinForm` through Visual Studio, based on the .NET Framework 2.0 version. Then I found `System.Windows.Forms.dll` based on the .NET Framework 2.0 version.

But the error trace-back was different from the previous anomaly:

[image: Error 02]

The code of the wrong line is because I called the `ShowDialog()` method. However, for `OpenFileDialog` objects, **Get; Set; properties can be used**.

Once I call the method, the Unity3D engine will prompt the wrong `"Null reference exception"`.

---

How do I solve the problem that `OpenFileDialog` can't be used in Unity3D?

In the Unity3d engine, what else can I do to dynamically read the files of an external folder?

Comment: If you need a file explorer, you could check this https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser. You cant use cloud build as Forms will be missing but you can build from editor.

Comment: thanks,I believe it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library that wraps the platform APIs: https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser

```cs
// Open file
var paths = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Open File", "", "", false);

// Open file async
StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanelAsync("Open File", "", "", false, (string[] paths) => {  });

// Open file with filter
var extensions = new [] {
    new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "png", "jpg", "jpeg" ),
    new ExtensionFilter("Sound Files", "mp3", "wav" ),
    new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*" ),
};
var paths = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Open File", "", extensions, true);

// Save file
var path = StandaloneFileBrowser.SaveFilePanel("Save File", "", "", "");

// Save file async
StandaloneFileBrowser.SaveFilePanelAsync("Save File", "", "", "", (string path) => {  });

// Save file with filter
var extensionList = new [] {
    new ExtensionFilter("Binary", "bin"),
    new ExtensionFilter("Text", "txt"),
};
var path = StandaloneFileBrowser.SaveFilePanel("Save File", "", "MySaveFile", extensionList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are looking for is someting along the lines of

```
OpenFileName ofn = new OpenFileName();
        ofn.structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(ofn);
        ofn.filter = "All Files\0*.*\0\0";
        ofn.file = new string(new char[256]);
        ofn.maxFile = ofn.file.Length;
        ofn.fileTitle = new string(new char[64]);
        ofn.maxFileTitle = ofn.fileTitle.Length;
        ofn.initialDir = UnityEngine.Application.dataPath;
        ofn.title = "Upload Image";
        ofn.defExt = "PNG";
        ofn.flags = 0x00080000 | 0x00001000 | 0x00000800 | 0x00000200 | 0x00000008;//OFN_EXPLORER|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST|OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST| OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT|OFN_NOCHANGEDIR
        if(DllTest.GetOpenFileName(ofn)) {
            FileDialogResult("file:///" + ofn.file);
        }
```

(I found it somewhere on te interwebs a while ago)